# Order of operations edge case in Mac osx calculator?

Tags: math, calculator, arithmetic-expressions, macos-high-sierra

I'm currently learning how to code in swift. So, I gave myself the challenge to code a calculator similar to the basic mac osx calculator.
My issue is that when I click:

```
 4 + 2 * 3 * = I get 30 - paper tape (4 * 2 * 3 + 6 = 30)
 4 * 2 + 3 * = I get 27 - paper tape (4 * 2 * 3 + 3 = 27)
 4 + 2 * 3 + = I get 20 - paper tape (4 + 2 * 3 + 10 = 20)
 4 * 2 + 3 + = I get 22 - paper tape (4 * 2 + 3 + 11 = 22)
```

I see the pattern but I do not understand 1 & 2, what's the reasoning in changing the + into a *. Is this mathematically correct (due to precedence) or is it a bug?

Comment: Wow that's weird. Probably a bug.

Comment: for the first one, 6 = 4+2. Most pocket calculators (including Windows calculators) also allow you to do quick maths like that, when it stores one operand for use later. For example press `3*4=` then `5=` then `6=` and it'll reuse the `*4` part and you can even press `=====` continuously without pressing any more keys

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @LưuVĩnhPhúc I did find out the functionality of storing operands and that is what I'm trying to implement. I am currently implementing cases where two or more operations are used. I am trying to understand the logic behind the first two cases in order to implement them. All the other cases I have implemented made sense to me mathematically so far, until those two.

Comment: Also, the mac os widget in the sidebar actually crashes in the first case after continuously clicking **** then =